# Convert matrix<float, 0, 1> to blob

Tags: c#, c++, sqlite, dlib

Suppose I have following vector in `c++`:

```
dlib::matrix<float, 0, 1> X;
```

I want to send `X` to `C#` then save in a column with `blob` data type.
what's the optimized way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `dlib::matrix<float, 0, 1> X;` is no `std::vector`. Please be more specific about your problem and preferably show us your code.

Comment: @churill thanks man, and yes X is not a vector. but about my problem: `X` is an array of 128 `float` number in length: `dlib::matrix<float, 0, 1> X`. now `X` must been sent to GUI in `C#` until this data is saved to corresponding column in `blob` datatype in my database in `sqlite`. probably i should convert datatype few times (`dlib`-> `c standard`-> `c#`-> `blob`)?? I want to find optimized way...